# Failure sending email

Tags: vb.net, smtp, sendmail

My test case is getting failed at `assert.fail()`, I am not having any clue what wrong it is going and where it is getting failed. Any idea to make this test case pass

Below is the test case

```
  <Test()> _
 Public Sub SendFtpFailureEmailShouldPassWithProcessingInfosAndSendEmail()
  Dim em As EmailNotification = New EmailNotification()
    Try
            Dim pfis As ProcessingFileInfos = New ProcessingFileInfos(New                FileInfo(AppSettingsReader.SchemaLocation), "Ftp") 
            Dim pfi1 As ProcessingFileInfo = New ProcessingFileInfo(New   FileInfo("Test1.xml"))
            pfi1.ContainsErrors = True
            pfi1.Message = "File Failed"
            pfi1.FileProcessStatus = "F"
            pfi1.Channel = "Ftp"
            pfis.Add(pfi1)

            Dim pfi2 As ProcessingFileInfo = New ProcessingFileInfo(New FileInfo("Test2.xml"))
            pfi2.ContainsErrors = True
            pfi2.Message = "File Failed on Bad Data"
            pfi2.FileProcessStatus = "F"
            pfi2.Channel = "Ftp"
            pfis.Add(pfi2)

            Dim result As String = em.CreateFtpFailureEmail(pfis)
            Assert.IsNotEmpty(result, "result is invalid")

            Dim emailDetails As Email = New Email() With {.Body = result, _
                                           .FromEmail = AppSettingsReader.TPLFromEmail, _
                                           .FromEmailName = AppSettingsReader.TPLFromEmailName, _
                                           .SmtpHost = AppSettingsReader.SmtpHost, _
                                           .Subject = "FTP Failure Report", _
                                           .ToEmail = "runu.ali@cdsglobal.co.uk"}
            em.SendEmail(emailDetails)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

sending mail code below:

```
  Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal emailObj As Email)

        Try
            If emailObj Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("emailObj", "emailObj cannot be null or empty")
            End If

            Dim em As New Net.Mail.MailMessage()

            em.From = New MailAddress(emailObj.FromEmail, emailObj.FromEmailName)
            em.To.Add(New MailAddress(emailObj.ToEmail))
            em.Subject = emailObj.Subject
            em.Body = emailObj.Body
            em.IsBodyHtml = True

            Dim SmTP As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
            SmTP.Host = emailObj.SmtpHost
            SmTP.Send(em)
        Catch ex As SmtpException
            Throw
        Catch ex As FormatException
            Throw


        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Well - what message do you get?

Comment: Failure sending email